# MergeSort on Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, mergesort

I'm fairly bad at coding so I really need some help as this homework is dued by Wednesday. I have seen mergesort normally split into three functions: (mergesort, sortedmerge, frontbacksplit, etc). But my professor's array based mergesort is done in one function so I'm assuming he wants us to only use one function as well for this linked list... (unless it is possible to implement a function within a function?) We have to write the function "struct listnode * mergesort(struct listnode *data)" and submit it to him. What I have done so far (I think) is splitting the linked list into 2 sub linked list but now I don't know how to "recursively" sort them.. Professor told us to write the function in C or C++, but the test code he provided us below is in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listnode { struct listnode * next;
                  long              value; } ;


//This is the function I need to write:
struct listnode * mergesort(struct listnode *data)
{   int temp, finished = 0;
    struct listnode *i, *j, *tail, *head, *ahead, *bhead, *atail, *btail;
    if ( a == NULL )
        return;
    head = data;
    tail = head->next;
    ahead = head;
    bhead = tail;
    i = ahead;
    j = bhead;
    tail = tail->next;
    while ( tail !=NULL ) {
        atail = tail;
        i->next = atail;
        i = i->next;
        tail = tail->next;
        btail = tail;
        j->next = btail;
        j = j->next;
        tail = tail->next;
    }

};

//Testing code provided by professor:
int main(void)
{
   long i;
   struct listnode *node, *tmpnode, *space;
   space =  (struct listnode *) malloc( 500000*sizeof(struct listnode));
   for( i=0; i< 500000; i++ )
   {  (space + i)->value = 2*((17*i)%500000);
      (space + i)->next = space + (i+1);
   }
   (space+499999)->next = NULL;
   node = space;
   printf("\n prepared list, now starting sort\n");
   node = mergesort(node);
   printf("\n checking sorted list\n");
   for( i=0; i < 500000; i++)
   {  if( node == NULL )
      {  printf("List ended early\n"); exit(0);
      }
      if( node->value != 2*i )
      {  printf("Node contains wrong value\n"); exit(0);
      }
      node = node->next;
   }
   printf("Sort successful\n");
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: There is no language called "C/C++", and this looks like C (but you should not cast `malloc` in C). In general, you should only tag the language you are writing/compiling.

Comment: As far as your question, you split to the simple case, then merge the resulting lists. In other words, the algorithm is the same.

Comment: The professor asked us to write the program in C or C++, however the test code he provided was in C though. I'm not familiar with C since I have only learned C++

Comment: This looks like C++ since code is not allowed in a struct in C.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews what do you mean ? Did you miss the closing brace ? It's on the right for some reason.

Comment: My bad. I was reading the function as the structure.  Need better glasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach:

```
if( list contains 0 or 1 item)
    return the list;  // it is already sorted
split the list into halves;
mergesort( first part);
mergesort( second part);
merge sorted parts;
return the merged list;
```

A list contains 0 or 1 item condition:

```
head == NULL || head->next == NULL
```

To split the list, you need to find its middle:

```
ahead = atail = head;       // first item
btail = head->next;         // second item
while(btail->next != NULL)  // anything left
{
    atail = atail->next;
    btail = btail->next;
    if( btail->next)
        btail = btail->next;
}
bhead = atail->next;        // disconnect the parts
atail->next = NULL;
```

To merge two sorted lists:

```
if(ahead->value <= bhead->value)  // set the head of resulting list
    head = tail = ahead, ahead = ahead->next;
else
    head = tail = bhead, bhead = bhead->next;

while(ahead && bhead)
    if(ahead->value <= bhead->value)  // append the next item
        tail = tail->next = ahead, ahead = ahead->next;
    else
        tail = tail->next = bhead, bhead = bhead->next;

if(ahead) // once one part got exhausted append the remaining other part
    tail->next = ahead;
else
    tail->next = bhead;
```